# Install pygrib fails with grib_api.h No such file error

Tags: pygrib

I'm installing pygrib library for Python 3.10.2 on Windows 10 and I get an error:

```
    pip3 install pygrib

tall pygrib src/pygrib\_pygrib.c(697): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include: 'grib_api.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I installed VC++.

How to fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned on https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/issues/115, I installed Pygrib with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygrib
```

And it works fine for me.